# Why do some lines in Stanza 2 of "Pastel" start with a colon?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, pavlo-tychyna, pavlo-tychyna-poetry-collection

from *Pastel* by Pavlo Tychyna:

> II
> The iron day
> Drank up some good wine
> Blossom, meadows! -
> :I've been walking-for a day-
> Graze, herds!-
> :to see my love- for a day-
> Ears of grain like cradles sway!-
> :during the day.
> The iron day
> Drank up some good wine

Why the colons in front of some lines? What does this mean?

Comment: Ru translation: https://stihi.ru/2017/06/01/9582

Comment: for me it seems like there are three exclamations, each followed by a part of the narration forming together "I've been walking-for a day - to see my love-for a day - _today_"

Comment: original text: https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=5533. The word after the last colon is "удень" = by day, in the daytime.

Comment: It seems a thing in Slavic poetry; Gennadiy Aygi (who wrote in Russian and the Turkic language Chuvash) [also did a lot of play with colons](https://www.jstor.org/stable/309471), although not the same kind of stuff. Very avant-garde.

Comment: Are you suggesting "II" is a colon, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to see these sentences if they are **written as a story and not a poem**:

> II
> The iron day. Drank up some good wine
> Blossom, meadows! - :I've been walking for a day-
> Graze, herds!- :to see my love- for a day-
> Ears of grain like cradles sway!- :during the day.
> The iron day. Drank up some good wine

The sentences after the colon are actually relating to the previous sentences, and hence not starting with the colon.